# Converting output of one function into array and feed value into variable in other function in ruby

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

For one of ruby programming logic, am trying to convert the string output of one function  into an array and from array have to feed the values to the variables declared in other function of the program

```
//response.each do |instance |
  print "#{instance.private_ip_address}"
  print "\n"
  end
//

10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
```

This output should be converted into array and feed as values in separate function of same program

```
def run_me
    ::
    ::
    filter_pattern = '[w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6!="*#{array[0]}*"&&w6!="*#{array[1]}*&&w6!="*#{array[2]}*"]'
```

So that the output of filter_pattern , should be like below

```
   '[w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6!="*10.1.1.1*"&&w6!="*10.1.1.2*"&&w6!="*10.1.1.3*"]'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Mocked responses for the sake of the example..
responses = [
  OpenStruct.new(request_type: 'GET', private_ip_address: '10.1.1.1'),
  OpenStruct.new(request_type: 'GET', private_ip_address: '10.1.1.2'),
  OpenStruct.new(request_type: 'GET', private_ip_address: '10.1.1.3')
]

data_of_ips = [] # Storing ips in this array from the loop for later usage in run_me method

responses.each do |instance|
  data_of_ips << instance.private_ip_address
end

# Now calling the run_me and pass the array as argument

run_me(data_of_ips)

# replace it in your filter like this
def run_me(ips)
  # 
  # 
  filter_pattern = '[w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6!="*#{ips[0]}*"&&w6!="*#{ips[1]}*&&w6!="*#{ips[2]}*"]'^Z
end
```

Comment: user1678123, but in the aws console I could see the w6!="*#{ips[0]}*"&&w6!="*#{ips[1]}*&&w6!="*#{ips[2]}*"]'  output instead of the corresponding IPs in the array

Comment: @Kavitha be more specific it is not clear what you mean by your comment